# erlang rfc4627 decode error

Tags: erlang, yaws

I am trying to decode json data in yaws, getting an error which is not clear to identify the issue. The Json data is

```
{
  "airport": [
    {"airport": "MAA"},
    {"city": "Chennai"},
    {"country": "India"},
    {"name": "Anna International Airport"}
  ]
}
```

The command i am using is

```
{ok, Json, _} = rfc4627:decode(Arg#arg.clidata).
```

The error is

> Exception: undef Req:
>   {http_request,'POST',{abs_path,"/sample/rest.yaws"},{1,1}} Stack:
>   [{rfc4627,decode,
>                    [<<"{\n  \"airport\": [\n    {\"airport\": \"MAA\"},\n    {\"city\": \"Chennai\"},\n    {\"country\":
>   \"India\"},\n    {\"name\": \"Anna International Airport\"}\n 
>   ]\n}">>],
>                    []},

Comment: You will have to give more information. The error you see does not look like it is directly tied to the problem you are seing.

Comment: This is the code https://gist.github.com/rgrajan/11204417, i am trying REST in yaws. Then i pass the JSON using Chrome-Advanced REST client to test the services.

Comment: The requested data as per line# 56 prints `Request Data <<"{\n  \"airport\": [\n    {\"airport\": \"MAA\"},\n    {\"city\": \"Chennai\"},\n    {\"country\": \"India\"},\n    {\"name\": \"Anna International Airport\"}\n  ]\n}">>:` in the yaws console. I guess the issue is because of the special characters `<<` and `>>`. This is automatically formatted.

Comment: @RajanR.G - the << and >> characters merely indicate a binary object in erlang. They would not

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an `undef` exception, indicating that you're calling an undefined function. The error shows the stack, and at the top of the stack is the `rfc4627:decode/1` function; that's the one that's undefined.

My guess is that your load path does not include the directory where you've stored the compiled `rfc4627` module. You can add that directory to the Yaws load path by modifying your `yaws.conf` file and adding something like the following to the global config section (near the top):

```
ebin_dir = /path/to/where/rfc4627/is/stored
```

Note that you're allowed to have multiple `ebin_dir` settings; each is added to the load path.